# Conditional and iterators in ruby

Tags: java, arrays, ruby, iterator, conditional-statements

I'm trying to translate the following code into ruby:

```
public void discardWeapon(Weapon w){
    if(!weapons.isEmpty()){
        boolean discarded = false;
        Iterator<WeaponType> it = weapons.iterator();   
        while(it.hasNext() && !discarded){
            WeaponType wtaux = it.next();
            if(wtaux == w.getWeaponType()){
                it.remove();
                discarded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, when it comes to the while loop, I can't really find a practical way to do it in ruby. I've got the following structure so far:

```
def discardWeapon(w)
  if(!@weapons.empty?)
    discarded = false
    @weapons.each do |wtaux|

    end
  end
end
```

But, how can I check my condition is met when using the .each iterator?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not something like `break if discarded` inside of your iteration?

Comment: Rather than trying to translate this line-by-line ad verbatim, think carefully about **what the function is actually trying to achieve**. Ruby is a very concise and elegant language; you can probably write that ugly java in a fraction of the code, using ruby.

Comment: How about this: `discarded = false; @weapons.delete_if { |weapon| discarded = true if !discarded && weapon.type == w.type }`

Comment: If found the function `myArray.delete_at(myArray.index(n) || myArray.length)`, which seems that can do the trick. Thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I read your Java code correctly, but it feels to me like you have an instance variable `@weapons` that holds an array of weapons and you want to discard one instance of a weapon `w` from that list.

```
def discard_weapon(weapon)
  index = @weapons.index(weapon)
  @weapons.delete_at(index) if index
end
```

[`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-index) returns the index of the first match. And [`Array#delete_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) deletes the element at the index when there was an element found.

When it is possible that the same weapon is included in the array multiple times and you want to discard all matching weapons then you can use the following one-liner:

```
def discard_weapon(weapon)
  @weapons.delete(weapon)
end
```